# On Laplace transforming an integrand

Tags: integration, laplace-transform

Suppose I have the following function:
$$
M(s) = \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{f(E)}{s+2\pi i /T(E)}\text{d}E \tag{1}
$$
Where $f(E)$ is some potentially complex function, $T(E)$ is some real function and $s$ is some complex variable. I *want* to use the following procedure:
$$
M(x) = \mathcal{L}^{-1}[M(s),x] = \int_{0}^{\infty}f(E)e^{-2\pi i x/T(E)}\text{d}E
$$
Since the inverse Laplace transform of $(s - a)^{-1}$ is $e^{ax}$. But then, I could get back to $s$ space with a normal Laplace transform:
$$
M(s) = \mathcal{L}[M(x),s] = \int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}f(E)e^{-2\pi i x/T(E)}\text{d}E\, e^{-x s} \text{d} x \tag{2}
$$

My question is: can you just do that? The motivation for this procedure is to circumvent the difficulties that might arise at the poles of $(1)$, since $(2)$ has no poles. These functions have to be computed numerically so my main concern is whether or not $(1)$ and $(2)$ are equivalent in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are confusing yourself.  So long as you can change the order of integration in (2) above, then the Laplace transform is pretty simple:

$$M(s) = \int_0^{\infty} dE \, f(E) \, \int_0^{\infty} dx \, e^{-[s+i 2 \pi/T(E)] x} = \int_0^{\infty} dE \, \frac{f(E)}{s+i 2 \pi/T(E)}$$

Comment: So, that's a yes? I was worried about if there were any sketchy rules about when you're allowed to do that (like, there are certain times when you can't interchange differentiation and integration when you're taking the derivative of an integral.)

Comment: You can change the order of integration so long as each integral is absolutely convergent.

Comment: Okey dokey, thanks.